# Duck tape versus electrical tape

Tags: duct-tape

My grandson has autism and has chewed up the cord to the computer. The wires are not cut but the insulation is gone.

Can I use duck tape till I get a new cord?

Comment: cord? Which one, the AC power cord? $5 at walmart, dont even mess with it.

Comment: @agentp Almost all desktops (Apple may be different) use a standard readily available cord. But laptop cords vary quite a bit, and often the cord is together with the power converter "brick".

Comment: Sorry to hear about the medical condition, but I should note that chewing through an AC wire (120 volts) can be deadly. You might research AFCI circuit breakers.

Comment: the OP didn't say anything about laptops. We could be talking about a keyboard wire too. Who knows..

Comment: @manassehkatz Apple isn't different.  They put a little plastic shroud on it to make it look cooler, but it is the same and is interchangeable.  The shroud is easily unclipped and reclipped  if you need to use an Apple cord on a normal device.

Comment: As an Alaskan i am legally required to say Use duct tape. BUT  gaffers tape would be awesome strong.

Comment: @Alaskaman Gaffer's tape is made for gaffers, so it's **made for electricians**, specifically *stage lighting electricians*. So one hopes they have at least given some sort of nod to the idea that the tape shouldn't conduct electricity.

Comment: i don't think any pro will condone such off-label use, but it's certainly better than nothing. vinyl is used in both tapes, and duct tape is not a conductor. In theory, moisture could seep into the reinforcing fibers of duct tape and cause issues, but that seems unlikely indoors.

Answer (score 2):

Electrical tape is designed not to conduct electricity.  Common duct tape is under no such design requirement, and shouldn't be used for anything electrical.